# Error while starting Rserve on Mac OS X Maverick

Tags: r, macos, rserve

I am trying to start Rserve using Rserve() command in R console but I am getting an error as `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R: line 141: exec: sh: not found`

I have Mac OSX Maverick. I installed R version 3.1.0. After this I tried to install Rserve using command **install.packages("Rserve")** after which in red color the message displayed was

```
trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/Rserve_1.7-3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 329829 bytes (322 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 322 Kb
```

After this I gave command **library(Rserve)** in R console and no error came but then when I gave command **Rserve()** to start the server I got the error which I have mentioned above.

I am unable to  understand why this error is coming. Is it because Rserve is not installed successfully? How else the Rserve can be installed? I tried to install Rserve through source package also. I downloaded the source package from rforge website and when I gave the command **install.packages("Rserve", type = "source")** I got the error as: 
`installation of package ‘Rserve’ had non-zero exit status`

Any help will be great!

Comment: You say "R console" but it's not clear how you started up the instance of R. Did you start R from a Terminal session? Aslo, which version of R did you install. There are two binary versions.

Comment: @BondedDust I didn't started R from Mac terminal. By "R console" I meant the normal R widow where we issue commands like install.packages(). Also I have already mentioned the version of R in above post `(version 3.1.0)`

Comment: "normal Mac window" and not starting from Terminal session suggests you are using the R.app GUI. That is _not_ recommended for Rserve initiation.

Comment: @BondedDust but everywhere on web thee is no mention of such limitation. Every where it is given that you can start the Rserve from normal R console(within R).

Comment: Best place to pose Q is R-SIG-Mac. I don't consider the R,app to be what is typically meant when people say "normal console" but Simon Urbanek would be the authority since he wrote much of both R.app and Rserve.

Answer (score 6):

I also had this problem today.

Rserve is using openSSL library that is deprecated in mac OS X 10.7 Lion.
This causes the error: `installation of package ‘Rserve’ had non-zero exit status`
So, I couldn't install Rserve by `install.packages('Rserve') in R console.

To avoid this, the binaries for mavericks was installable for me:

> http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/

I downloaded `Rserve_1.7-3.tgz` and did `R CMD INSTALL Rserve_1.7-3.tgz`
Then I could run Rserve by `library(Rserve)` and `Rserve()` in R console.

It seems that latest version of `Rserve 1.8` is not available.(?)

Comment: Still have the problem on Yosemite, today.

Answer (score 3):

To do this from inside R, you can run the following:

```
pkg_url <- "http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/Rserve_1.7-3.tgz"
install.packages(pkg_url, repos = NULL)
```

where the package URL was obtained from the link for "Mavericks binaries" on the [CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rserve/index.html) (towards the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened to me when I ran the function `Rserve()`
It gave an error - Fatal error: you must specify `--save`, `--no-save` or `--vanilla`

So I tried using this code, and the server got initiated.

```
Rserve::run.Rserve()
```

I hope this helps.